# java - can't make http request on port other than 80

Tags: java, http, url, port

My java program is hitting **"http://url:port"** kind of url to fetch some data. On my local windows machine deployed on tomcat 6, it is working fine. But on production which is a linux machine having tomcat 6 on it, it gives me connection timeout.

Ironically, if I hit the URL without port number, it will successfully bring me the output but not with port. Not finding any clue, please help.

The snippet of code I am using to connect and fetch data is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("59.162.167.36:80/api/…");
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to connect?

Comment: Assuming your configuration of tomcat 6 is the same (i.e. both binding to the same port) then it sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: Does url-http://url:80 also gives the error?

Comment: try{
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://59.162.167.36:80/api/MessageCompose?user=user&pass=pass");
   httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0");
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious possibility is that a firewall in front of your production machine is blocking access to that port. Check the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is straightforward: On production you don't have that port opened, contact the administrator, or the hosting and issue your problem. Of course they will confirm my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly your hosting provider implements a firewall of some description in the data center. This is common practice. Send them a message asking if port X is blocked, and if so can they open it.